# Exception occurred while reading mails from exchange server 2010 using imap

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am trying to read the mails from the exchange server 2010 , however sometimes the connection got established , but remaining times program gives below exception:

**javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: LOGIN failed**

The code is working fine with the exchange server 2007 . But from the time mailbox has been migrated to 2010, the program is behaving in this fashion only.

I have also tried with several options available on net, but nothing is working. I am using javamail-1.4.4 API version . Here is the piece of code through which I am just trying to connect to the mailbox .

```
   public class ReadMail {

 static Store store=null;
    static String host="";
    static String username="";
    static String password="";


public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception{
      try{
          Session session;
          username = "username";
          password = "password";
              host = "hostname";
          Properties props = System.getProperties();
          props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth","true");
          session = Session.getInstance(props, 
                                    new ExchangeAuthenticator(username, password));
          Store st = session.getStore("imaps");
          st.connect(host,username, password);
          System.out.println("Connected");

    }
      catch (Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace(System.out);
      }
}

}
```

```
public class ExchangeAuthenticator extends Authenticator {

    String user;
    String pw;

    public ExchangeAuthenticator (String username, String password)
    {
       super();
       this.user = username;
       this.pw = password;
    }
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
    {
      return new PasswordAuthentication(user, pw);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I also face same problem in my code i set two properties in my code 
disable plain test and enable NTLM

props.setProperty("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable","true"); 
props.setProperty("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");

now my code able to connect with exchange server

read it

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1587688

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the configuration of the server has changed and it's no longer accepting your credentials, or no longer supporting any of the login methods that JavaMail supports.

[Turn on session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) and examine the protocol trace.  It should provide some clues as to why it's failing.

You might also want to upgrade to JavaMail 1.4.5, which has built-in support for NTLM authentication, which you might need.

Comment: there is no issue with the credentials , as I have already mentioned in my question , that I am able to connect to the server sometime successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Even though your credentials are OK, the new server might not accept your login method. For instance, the new server might not allow "Plain" authentication.

The debugging info should show which authentication methods are accepted.